# How to make a div mask its parent's background

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, slider

So I'm making a seekable video progress bar, and I need the playhead to have a transparent border around it, but such that it masks out progress bar that contains it and shows underlying video. Here's a diagram of what I need to do.

[image]

Assuming the diagonal lines represent the video playing underneath the progress bar, you can see how the border around the playhead should mask out the progress bar. Is there a good browser-safe way to do this?

Comment: Are you saying you would like 3 elements, the top element causing the 2nd element to be transparent, showing the bottom element?  Fairly certain that's not possible.

Comment: can you show the code you are using to get it this far without the transparent border etc? Make a JSFiddle as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create the video container first. Then, we create a container to house the seeker within. The seeker contains the 3 pieces that make up the 'scrollbar'. the left line, seek button, and right line.

```
<div class="video">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="seeker">
            <div class="left-line"></div>
            <div class="seek-button"><a href="#"></a></div>
            <div class="right-line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS to create the effect that you'er going for:

```
.video{
    width:920px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#ecebeb;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container{
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    margin:5%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.seeker{
    width:90%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25px;
    left:5%;
    height:15px;
}
.left-line{
    width:200%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:-154%;
    background:#000;
}
.right-line{
    height:100%;
    width:200%;
    position:absolute;
    right:-154%;
    background:#000;
}
.seek-button{
    width:8%;
    height:25px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-4%;
    margin-top:-5px;   
}
.seek-button a{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:10px;
    background:#000;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
```

What's impotant to note in the css is just the left and right offsets. we're simply creating lines that are as big as the element area and then offsetting them to the left and right. Since we're using % values for the width of everything, this is responsive..

Last but not least, include the jQUery UI library and leverage the `draggable` function, declare a handle and exclude all dragging except for from this handle:

```
$('.seeker').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    handle: '.seek-button a',
    containment: [-280, null, 475, null]
});
```

The `containment` property above is the `x1,y2,x2,y2` coordinates within the `.seeker` element. `null` indicates that we wish to leave the `y` axis alone completely and only constrain the horizontal movement between these two coordinates.

That should be all you need.

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwhkgsxy/)